# Check id every value in ";" separated string exists on a LOV list using just Excel formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In a cell I have a multi value separated by semicolon like this:
Red;Blue;Green
I need to compare if each of those values exist on a list:
Black
Orange
Green
Blue
Red
I think it should be an array formula, but I have no idea how to set it.
Is it even possible?
Regards
Michał

Comment: Since you need to split the text, i don't think it can be done just by a formula. You may need to write a UDF (VBA) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not mentioned what output you are looking for. Below are the two possible solution.

***1.*** If you are looking for the count of words in a cell from the list use following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND($E$2:$E$6,$A2))*1)
```

[image]

***2.*** If you want words in the cell that are in the list to be displayed in separate columns, use the following array formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($J$2:$J$6,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND($J$2:$J$6,$A2)),ROW($J$2:$J$6)-ROW($J$1)),COLUMNS($A1:A1))),"")
```

Drag/copy above formula across and down as required.
Being an array formula you'll have to commit this formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: First solution is so beautiful, love it.

Comment: Well I haven't tested it yet (have a lot to do) but i see it will fit. I'll accept it as soon as it will be tested.

Comment: Not perfect but it cannot be done better using only formulas. I've added LEN formula to check repetitions in $A2 cell. It is not going to work when semicolon is ommited :( but gives true/false response if any of values divided with semicolon is out of list.
=NOT(SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND($E$2:$E$6;$A2))*1)=(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2;";";""))+1)) @Mrig

Comment: Youv'e added d in the middle of Green resulting in "Greedn" but if we add d at the end resulting "Greend" it doesn't work. But still it is the best solution achieved with formulas. I've applied it and accepted as an answer, its gooood :). @Mrig

Answer (score 0):

You can write this UDF and use it as a formula. Wasn't sure what output is required. This UDF gives number of items that match in the list.

**Parameters:**

`myValue` - the cell that contains multi value separated by semicolon

`listRange` - Range that has the list to check against. Should be a single column list

```
Function checkList(myValue As Range, listRange As Range) As Integer
    Dim t As Variant
    t = Split(myValue.Value, ";")

    Dim c As Integer
    c = 0
    For i = LBound(t) To UBound(t)
        For j = 1 To listRange.Rows.Count
            If (t(i) = listRange(j, 1)) Then
                c = c + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    checkList = c
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to do this only with excel formulas, the input string has to be split to multiple cells before comparing it with the list.

If your input string is in `A1`, use the below formula and drag it right to split them based on the delimiter `;`.

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,";",REPT(" ",999)),1+((COLUMN(A1)-1)*999),999))
```

[image]

Assuming your list is in `column G`, use the below formula which counts the strings `Red, Blue and Green` in your list and returns `Found` or `Not found`.

in `C2`,

```
=IF(COUNTIF($G:$G,C1),"Found","Not found")
```

Hope this helps.